# Android - libraries R files not generated when more libraries depends on support-v4

Tags: android, android-support-library

my Android project depends on 3 libraries, one of them (**A**) has no requirements, two of them (**B**, **C**) require support-v4 library because of Fragments. The project itself requires support-v4 library as well. The project and the libraries have build target Android 2.2 (API 8). All android-support-v4.jar libs are the same build and version.

When I add library **A**, its *R.java* is generated in project's *gen* folder. But when I add library **B** or **C**, theirs *R.java* are not generated and even **A**'s *R.java* is removed from the project's *gen* folder.

Is there a way to include libraries which themselves require support-v4 library? Other than copying their code to the project and not include them as libs.

**Update:**

I found the problem. The problem was that both my libs B and C used same package name in Manifest. When I changed package name of one library all R.java appeared.

My libs packages were eu.anycode.android.app as both extend com.android.app classes. But I don't want them in one library as I don't need to keep them together as there are projects where I need just one of them and I don't want to include unused code to the final APK.

So my another question is if it's possible to set it up so I can use same package name for different libraries?

-- Martin

Comment: You are using Eclipse, right? After you added the library and the support-v4 to the libraries, go to build and rebuild everything. Should normally fix it.

Comment: thank for your answer, I tried to rebuild several times. Finally I found the problem, see my edited question. -- Martin

Comment: @MartinEdlman - Post your solution to the original question as an answer and mark it as such. For your other question you should ask a new question in the site. Remember that this serves future visitors as well so you cannot overload multiple questions in one place.

Answer (score 0):

> So my another question is if it's possible to set it up so I can use same package name for different libraries?

No, this is not possible. Package names are unique.

Comment: Thank, I solved the issue by setting different package name in Manifest but kept same package names in sources. It works that way.